# How to achieve the flow of execution in a Stored Proc and get an table output

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

How can we achieve the flow of execution in a Stored Proc and get a table output? Is this possible to call `DEMO_PROC` and get the output of (`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #TEMP_TABLE`) mentioned in the proc? Or is there any alternate way by which this can be achieved?

Sample code:

```
CREATE PROC DEMO_PROC AS
BEGIN
if object_id('Tempdb..#TMP') is not null
drop table #TMP 

select 
O.ID, O.NAME, O.E_ID, P.PKG_ID
into #TEMP_TABLE
from Order_Table AS O
join  
Package_Table AS P on P.ID = O.ID

WHERE P.PKG_NAME IN (1,2)

ALTER TABLE #TEMP_TABLE ADD COL_V1 nvarchar(100);
UPDATE #TEMP_TABLE set COL_V1 = (SELECT assw FROM Order_Table AS O join ELEC_TABLE AS E ON O.E_ID = E.E_ID
                                where E.E_ID = #TEMP_TABLE.E_ID
                                and (E.E_DESC LIKE '%U R SUPER, Thanks! in advance%'))

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM #TEMP_TABLE
END
```

Comment: we can query table with in procedure and store in variable. What problem you want to solve by this?

Answer (score 0):

A table name can be passed to the stored procedure and created inside the SP.  Then it can be queried in the calling sql.  A table name can returned from the SP and queried in the calling sql.